# One UISwitch in UITableView for 4 cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a `UITableView`, and I want four cells, each with a `UISwitch` that acts independently. Do I have to have 4 prototype cells, or can I use just one cell and configure it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `UITableviewCell` that contains a `UISwitch` and in

**tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)**

you could configure each cell independently.

So, to respond to your question: yes create just one Cell and configure it.

Comment: Ok Thanks - Would I put the IBAction in the Cell file or the viewcontroller File?

Comment: Put the IBAction in the Cell because the Cell will handle the action and not the ViewController.

Comment: What do you mean by kind of ? What is not working ?